# Require not defined in socket.io implementation in .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm unable to perform chat functionality in my application. I have created a port 8000 on which my applicattion runs. I'm trying to implement the socket.io module inside my application. For this i have created another file named as chat.js. Firstly I define socket as socket= io(). Then it was showing error as

```
//GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NAO4VZg 404 6.362 ms - 1908"
```

Then after lots of searches i found the replacement for the above statement as

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8000/users/chatter', { transports: ['websocket'] })
```

Now running the code with this statement. The below error is displaying:

```
chat.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
  at chat.js:1
```

Here is the screenshot of error:
[image: Error Screenshot]

After lots of searches i found the replacement for the above statement as

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8000/users/chatter', { transports: ['websocket'] })
var message = document.getElementById('message'),
      handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
      btn = document.getElementById('send'),
      output = document.getElementById('output'),
      feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

// Emit events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
    });
    message.value = "";
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
})

// Listen for events
socket.once('connect', socketConn => {
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
});

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message...</em></p>';
});
});
```

Now running the code with this statement. The below error is displaying:

```
chat.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
  at chat.js:1
```

Comment: You cannot use `require` in client-side (browser) JavaScript. You need to use a `<script>` tag as usual.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: then how could i use it ?

Comment: I assume you initially tried this? https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client. You **cannot** user `require` in the browser - that's a `CommonJS` thing that browsers don't support, so unless you have a build system in place, `require` won't work.

Comment: on your frontend just use socket.io-client.js which you can find https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io and then inside your script tag's just create `var socket = io(options)`; ofc give options if needed =)

Comment: how can i use socket.io-client.js

Comment: It's the first code snippet in that `GitHub` repo I linked.

Comment: Thanks to all of your for response. I sorted out my problem.